# If a sequence converges according to one metric, must it converge according to all metrics?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Given a sequence of points in a metric space, with a given metric $d$, will the same sequence of elements converge if you change the metric of that metric space?

Comment: Yes if the metrics induce the same topology. Not necessarily if they induce different topologies.

Comment: See [equivalence of metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics).  In particular, if metrics $d_1,d_2$ satisfy an inequality $\alpha d_2(x,y) \leq d_1(x,y) \leq \beta d_2(x,y)$ for all $x,y$ then $d_1,d_2$ are equivalent and the set of convergent sequences will be the same.  The most familiar metrics on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (Euclidean, $l_p$, Taxicab) are all equivalent.  But metrics in general may not be (as the answers below show.)

Answer (score 6):

No. Let $X=\mathbb Q$. If $d$ is the usual metric, the sequence $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is convergent. But if you change the metric to the discrete metric $d'$:
$$
d'(a,b)=\begin{cases}1,&\ a\ne b\\0,&\ a=b\end{cases}
$$
the same sequence is not Cauchy.

Answer (score 3):

No. The sequence $\left(\frac1n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges in $[0,1]$  (to $0$) with respect to the usual metric, but not with respect to the discrete metric.

However, the answer will be affirmative if both metrics induce the same topology.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that doesn't involve the discrete metric:

Consider the half-open interval $[0,2\pi)$, once with the metric $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$, and once with the metric $d_2(x,y)=2\sin\frac{|x-y|}{2}$. And consider the sequence $a_n=2\pi-\frac{1}{n}$.

According to $d_1$, this sequence does not converge in the interval (it can't converge to $2\pi$ because that's not in the interval), but according to $d_2$ is converges to $0$.